# Jmeter load testing with multiple user credentials and form filling

Tags: performance, jmeter, load

I am new in jmeter and I am doing r&nd on Jmeter. I have a scenario can you help me regarding this.

```
1.I have one login form and one details form. User can first do login and then he can fill details form. 
2.I want to test this steps through jmeter. 
3.But, I want to test multiple user can login together and can fill details form together at the same time. 
4.So how can I pass both login and details csv at the same time In jmeter.
```

Please guide me. If any video or blog please share.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have 2 CSV files, one with credentials, other with the form data - just use 2 [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) elements and point them to different files
2. If you have more than 2 CSV files, i.e. first file has credentials and the name of the CSV file with details for each particular user, you won't be able to use 2nd CSV Data Set Config, you will have to go for [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) like it's described in [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime/) article